# Violin plot with outline different alpha than fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a violin plot. I want the outline to be the same color as the fill, but just a different alpha level.  How do I do this?

```
# define the ggplot object
v1 <- ggplot(spread, aes(x = device, y = value, fill = implant)) +
  geom_violin(position = "identity", alpha = 0.4, color = aes(fill = implant)) +
  facet_wrap(~ n, 
             labeller = as_labeller(function(x) paste0("n =", x)), 
             ncol = 7) +
  labs(x = "device", y = expression( ~ bar(x)^" *"),
       title = expression( "Spread and density of "~ bar(x)^" *" ~ "estimates for " ~ italic(n) ~ " repeat measures." ), 
       subtitle = expression (italic("Derived from 1,000 bootstrap estimates for each ") ~ italic(n))) +
  theme_gdocs() +
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        plot.title = element_text(family = "arial", size = 14), 
        plot.subtitle = element_text(family = "sans", size = 10, margin = margin(t=-6)), 
        strip.text = element_text(family = "sans", size = 10, margin = margin(t=8, b=4))
  )

# render the plot
plot(v1)
```

I get this, which is nice, I just want to add a darkened outline around the two plots for A/B.  I want the outline to be the same color as the fill, just at `alpha = 0.8` or something.

I tried this, but it gave me an error.

```
geom_violin(position = "identity", alpha = 0.4, color = aes(fill = implant, alpha = 0.8))
```

[image: the plot as it is now]

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, but you can try using some colors that have `alpha` included in the color itself (since you are not mapping to alpha), using `rgb(r, g, b, alpha)`. However, the `alpha` parameter in the violins are only applied to the fill, so the colors will have an alpha of 1. So to get a dark outline you just have to add `color = implant` to the aesthetics.

Comment: (So `aes(x = device, y = value, fill = implant, color = implant)` is probably all you need.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `after_scale` to make the color be based on the fill, but with independent control of the alpha:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, 
       aes(gear, mpg, 
           fill = factor(am), 
           color = after_scale(alpha(fill, 0.6)), # TWEAK THIS
           group = interaction(gear, am))) +
  geom_violin(position = "identity", alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]

or with 0.2:

[image]

Comment: This worked. Than you so much!